# Realm - Deleting Object No Longer Present

Tags: realm

How can Realm handle deletes so that it can maintain the correct number of objects? i.e delete realm objects that no longer exist from the main data source.

lets pretend we have a `User` and property is just `name`

**database**

- User:john
- User:suzie
- User:jim

On initial load, all these users are loaded into Realm

Now i decide to delete User:jim from the database

**database**

- User:john
- User:suzie

**Realm** still has reference to `User:jim`

- User:john
- User:suzie
- User:jim

Now I can easily clear the User table in Realm and then just do a re-insert. However this is not the ideal solution if you have thousands of Users.

Is there some way to easily query the new collection with that of Realm and just remove the User that is no longer present?

Answer (score 0):

No, that kind of negative search is not possible, and I doubt you can do better than O(n*m) in any case. If you add indexes it will speed it up but it still scales just as bad.

Depending on how your data is structured, it might be easier to just delete all users and add them again?

Comment: The Users were just an example, it could be any object so I just wanted to know what could be done. At this stage is delete all and re-add, or possibly use a delete/stale flag which you can use to delete on the realm side, but then you'd have to actually delete them from the database.